# Change color of a specific row in jtable that is fetched from jar file

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change color of a specific row in `jtable` that is fetched from jar file

```
Statement stmt = myConn.createStatement();

String sqlQuery = ("Select * from ATTENDENCE where Class='"+c+"' AND Section='"+s+"' AND Date='"+date+"';");

ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
while(result.next())
{
    String ad = result.getString("Status");      
    if (ad.equalsIgnoreCase("absent"))
    {
        setForeground(Color.red);
    }
    table_1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a renderer and apply it.

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
```

The class renderer should be like that (for example):

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6703872492730589499L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if(row == 0){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if ( row == 1){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: You apply the `renderer` when you create the `jTable` (after initalization)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlQuery = ("Select * from ATTENDENCE where Class='"+c+"' AND Section='"+s+"' AND Date='"+date+"';");
```

Don't use string concatenation to build your SQL query. This is error prone, hard to read and hard to maintain.

Instead you should use a `PreparedStatement`. This allows you to specify multiple tokens which can then be replaced by the value of your variable:

```
String sql = "Select * from Attendance where Class = ? and Section = ? and Date = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, c);
...
stmt.setDate(3, date);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

> I want to change color of a specific row

Looks like you want to color a row based on a value in the row.

Rendering is done when the table is painted, not when you get the data from the database.

One way to do this is to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the JTable. Something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if (!isRowSelected(row))
        {
            c.setBackground(getBackground());
            int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            String status = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, ???);
            if ("absent".equals(status)) c.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        return c;
    }
};
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and working examples to get you started.